# Как сделать обновление comboBox, при добавлении данных в бд

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

У меня есть 2 окна, 1-ое главное, из него запускается второе.

Второе окно используется для добавления данных в бд, и последующий вывод на первом окне, на первом окне есть `comboBox` с метками, которые берутся из бд.

Мне нужно, чтобы когда пользователь запускает 2 окно, вводит данные, и нажимает `Ok`, чтобы `comboBox` на первой странице обновлялся с новыми данными.

Как это можно сделать? Привожу ниже код 1 и 2 окна без ненужных вещей (считайте что база данных есть).

1-ое окно:

```
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import uic
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
    from add_receipt import add_receipt
    import sqlite3
    
    
    class Recepts(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            uic.loadUi('recepts.ui', self)
            self.add_receipt = add_receipt()
    
        def call_add_receipt(self):
            self.add_receipt.show()
            while not self.add_receipt.added_new_recept:
                pass
            self.update()
```

2-е окно:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
import sys
import sqlite3


class add_receipt(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(add_receipt, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('new_recept.ui', self)
     def accepted(self):
        if self.lineEdit.text().strip() == '':
            self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid red')
        elif self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText().strip() == '':
            self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid red')
        elif self.lineEdit_2.text().strip() == '':
            self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid red')
        else:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO 
            recepts(title, description, marks) VALUES(?, ?, ?)""",
                                (self.lineEdit.text(), self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText().replace("\n", 
"\t"),
                                 ' '.join(self.lineEdit_2.text().split())))
            self.lineEdit_2.clear()
            self.lineEdit.clear()
            self.plainTextEdit.clear()
            self.added_new_recept = True
            self.close()
```

Это Ui первого окна:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui version="4.0">
     <class>MainWindow</class>
     <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>353</width>
        <height>458</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="windowTitle">
       <string>Книга рецептов</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>60</x>
          <y>130</y>
          <width>191</width>
          <height>22</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>353</width>
         <height>21</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <widget class="QMenu" name="menu">
        <property name="title">
         <string>Возможности</string>
        </property>
        <addaction name="action"/>
       </widget>
       <addaction name="menu"/>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
      <action name="action">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Добавить рецепт</string>
       </property>
      </action>
     </widget>
     <resources/>
     <connections/>
    </ui>
```

Это ui второго окна:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui version="4.0">
     <class>Form</class>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>615</width>
        <height>495</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="windowTitle">
       <string>Form</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="verticalLayoutWidget">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>29</x>
         <y>22</y>
         <width>561</width>
         <height>431</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
        <property name="spacing">
         <number>20</number>
        </property>
        <item>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
            <property name="sizePolicy">
             <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
              <horstretch>0</horstretch>
              <verstretch>0</verstretch>
             </sizepolicy>
            </property>
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>120</width>
              <height>0</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="font">
             <font>
              <pointsize>10</pointsize>
             </font>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Метки(записывать через пробел без запятых):</string>
            </property>
            <property name="alignment">
             <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2"/>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="buttonBox">
          <property name="standardButtons">
           <set>QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok</set>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
     <resources/>
     <connections/>
    </ui>
```

*Я сократил всё, и оставил только то что `не понимаю`

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Вот, я добавил ещё ui окон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow
import sqlite3

#from add_receipt import AddReceipt             # - add_receipt, + AddReceipt
class AddReceipt(QtWidgets.QDialog):            # - QWidget,     + QDialog
    def __init__(self):
        super(AddReceipt, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('new_recept.ui', self)            
     
    '''    
    def accepted(self):
                if self.lineEdit.text().strip() == '':
            self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid red')
        elif self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText().strip() == '':
            self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid red')
        elif self.lineEdit_2.text().strip() == '':
            self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid red')
        else:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO 
            recepts(title, description, marks) VALUES(?, ?, ?)""",
                                (self.lineEdit.text(), self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText().replace("\n", 
"\t"),
                                 ' '.join(self.lineEdit_2.text().split())))
            self.lineEdit_2.clear()
            self.lineEdit.clear()
            self.plainTextEdit.clear()
            self.added_new_recept = True
            self.close()
    '''    

class Recepts(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('recepts.ui', self)  

        self.menu.triggered.connect(self.call_add_receipt)                       # +++    
        
        self.add_receipt = AddReceipt()
        self.add_receipt.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self._accepted)              # +++
        self.add_receipt.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.add_receipt.reject)     # +++        

    def call_add_receipt(self):                                                  # +++
        self.add_receipt.exec_()                                            # - show(), + exec_()
        
    def _accepted(self):                                                    # +++
        if not self.add_receipt.lineEdit_2.text():
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', 
                'Введите <b>Метки</b> или нажмите <b>Cancel</b>.')
            return
        _list = self.add_receipt.lineEdit_2.text().split()                  # - strip(), + split()
        self.comboBox.clear()
        self.comboBox.addItems(_list)
        self.add_receipt.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Recepts()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Proskima что не так?

Comment: Спасибо большое, я просто пытался осмыслить код)